# Update multiple leaflet locations if value

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

i have a vehicle tracking api that I am attempting to consume in leaflet. My idea is that is the vehicle driving value is true, then update the location. Ideally, it would be if the location is different, but starting small.

Below is what I have that works for one vehicle, but am unsure how to apply this to 150 or so vehicles

```
var ism;

function update_position() {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:5000/live_events', function(data) {
        var latitude = myjson._items[0]['latitude'];
        var longitude = myjson._items[0]['longitude'];
    if (!ism) {
        ism = L.marker([latitude,longitude]).bindPopup("I am driving").addTo(map);
    }
    ism.setLatLng([latitude,longitude]).update();
    setTimeout(update_position, 1000);
});
}
if  (myjson._items[0]['isDriving'] = "True") {
  update_position();
}
```

So this would be updating every 5, 10, 15 seconds, whatever and loading under 200 vehicles. Does anyone know an optimized way to accomplish this and have it work for all vehicles?